# how to save table state even after changing table pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable that displays data from a database. I'ts displayed in a bootstrap modal and there is an option in each row to delete the row.

Here's the jquery that gets the data from the database:

```
function cart_contents() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "cartContents.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){
                var table = $('#cart-content').dataTable();
                table.fnDestroy();
                table.dataTable({
                    "aaData": data,
                    "scrollX": false,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "pageLength": 6,
                    "language": {
                        "info": "Number of items: _TOTAL_"
                    },
                    "searching": false,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {"sTitle": "Product", "mData": "product"},
                        {"sTitle": "Price", "mData": "price"},
                        {"sTitle": "Qty.", "mData": "quantity"},
                        {
                            "sTitle": "Edit", "mData": "id", "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                                return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="sample(' + mData + ')">Edit</button>';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "mData": "id", "render": function (mData, type, row, meta){
                                return "<span style='cursor: pointer' class='close' onclick='remove_product(this," + mData + ")'>x</span>";
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
}
```

Here's the remove_product:

```
function remove_product(these, id){
    var i = these.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("cart-content").deleteRow(i);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "remove_product.php",
        data: {product_id: id},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Now, the data may or may not exceed a single page on the table since it is set to display 6 rows. Therefore, there is a chance that there may be pagination. Whenever the 'x' is clicked to remove the row, it removes it on the page, and successfully deletes it in the database.

However, when I scroll to the next page of the table and go back previously, the row that was deleted comes back. How would I go about deleting it permanently, since it no longer exists in the database? I need to do this without reloading the modal.

Comment: use `table.row(selector).remove()` it will delete the row from datatables, your function only delete the row from the DOM, which is controlled by datatables pagination.

Comment: can you please explain how to use the function? what does the parameter 'selector' take?